# Select Multiple rows in single column separated by New Line

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have a table with values look like this.

```
    Id Name Fruit
    ------------
    1 Jon  Apple
    ------------
    2 Jon  Orange
    ------------
    3 Jon  Grape
    ------------
    4 Mike Apple
    ------------
    5 Mike Orange
    -------------
```

How to distinct the column into something like this in mysql?

```
    Name Fruit
    ----------
    Jon  Apple
         Orange
         Grape
    -----------
    Mike Apple
         Orange
    -----------
```

Comment: are those two different columns? Even if they are you will not be able to do it in query

Comment: That's rather a job for the presentation layer than for a relational DBMS.

Comment: yes,different columns

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(fruit SEPARATOR '\n') FROM your_table GROUP BY name
```

[Demo in db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f01d9785749fd826f47566ffeddc655a)

Update to add numbering:

```
SELECT name ,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT (rn,')',fruit) SEPARATOR '\n')
FROM (
    SELECT * 
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS rn
    FROM your_table
    ) SQ
GROUP BY name
```

[Demo with numbering in db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=731c2f08f6eefc9653045589c517ab96)

Comment: Great.This one works..but I replace the '\n' with '<br>' because  '\n' in php looks like adding space in between.Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy Thanks again.Can I put numbering inside group_concat eg. 1)Apple 2)Orange etc..

Comment: @AmirulFahmi, Yes you can do the numbering. Updated the answer. If you are using MySQL 8+  you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` directly. if not use this [LINK](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) to emulate the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is also using `joins` to achieve this requirement.

```
select 
    case when t1.id = t2.id then t1.name else '' end 
    , t3.fruits
from 
    (select min(id) id, name from testA
        group by name) t1
left join
    testA t2 on t2.name = t1.name
left join
    testA t3 on t3.id = t2.id
order by t2.id asc
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=i1u5fHULuB).

Comment: Thanks.This one works but I need the fruit result in one row for each name.